# Can't get cost function for logistic regression to work

Tags: c#, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm trying to implement logistic regression by myself writing code in C#. I found a library (Accord.NET) that I use to minimize the cost function. However I'm always getting different minimums. Therefore I think something may be wrong in the cost function that I wrote.

```
static double costfunction(double[] thetas)
    {
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double[][] theta_matrix_transposed = MatrixCreate(1, thetas.Length);
        while(i!=thetas.Length) { theta_matrix_transposed[0][i] = thetas[i]; i++;}
        i = 0;

        while (i != m) // m is the number of examples
        {
            int z = 0;
            double[][] x_matrix = MatrixCreate(thetas.Length, 1);
            while (z != thetas.Length) { x_matrix[z][0] = x[z][i]; z++; } //Put values from the training set to the matrix
            double p = MatrixProduct(theta_matrix_transposed, x_matrix)[0][0];

            sum += y[i] * Math.Log(sigmoid(p)) + (1 - y[i]) * Math.Log(1 - sigmoid(p));

            i++;
        }
        double value = (-1 / m) * sum;
        return value;
    }

    static double sigmoid(double z)
    {
        return 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-z));
    }
```

*x* is a list of lists that represent the training set, one list for each feature. What's wrong with the code? Why am I getting different results every time I run the L-BFGS? Thank you for your patience, I'm just getting started with machine learning!

Answer (score 0):

That is very common with these optimization algorithms - the minima you arrive at depends on your weight initialization. The fact that you are getting different minimums doesn't necessarily mean something is wrong with your implementation. Instead, check your gradients to make sure they are correct using the finite differences method, and also look at your train/validation/test accuracy to see if they are also acceptable.

Comment: Since when does logistic regression have multiple minimas?

Comment: Of course it can have multiple minimas, depending on your problem and weight initialization. For example, if you randomly initialize your weights and plot the decision function of logistic regression each time you run your program, you will see that it is slightly different each time (unless the problem/data is incredibly trivial). This is a result of arriving at different minimas in the cost function.

Comment: You must have a different definition of a convex function (which the logistic regression error function is) than the rest of the world then.

Comment: A convex function like that cost function must have a global minimum, indeed. I've run further tests and it seems that for certain initial values it returns the right results, but for others it does not, giving NaN errors. In fact, it may happen that the software, inside the cost function, has to compute log(0). In these cases, the minimisation doesn't work.